# Expressing the Catalan numbers as a function of the Taylor series of $e^{-x}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion, catalan-numbers

Is there a known way of expressing the Catalan numbers or the generating function of the Catalan numbers as a function of the Taylor series of $e^{-x}$ i.e.

$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}-...$?

I have been looking all over for this, and even though I happen to come across several different representations of the Catalan numbers, I cannot seem to find one involving this formula.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The exponential generating function of the Catalan numbers is given by
$$ e^{2x}(I_0(2x)-I_1(2x)),$$
where $I_n(x)$ is the $n-$th [Modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).
In theory, you can apply the [Borel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) of the usual generating function to get this.